# Node.js heroku deploy failure

Tags: node.js, heroku

My app works locally, but when trying to deploy I get code=H10. I have tried looking up code=H10 failures, but they all see to lead to changes with process.env.PORT changes, which I have already done in various ways.

This is my first time deploying to heroku, so sorry if I am missing some important information.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

My logs:

```
2021-05-16T23:27:11.291289+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
2021-05-16T23:27:11.291289+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
2021-05-16T23:27:11.291289+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-05-16T23:27:11.291290+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: []
2021-05-16T23:27:11.291290+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-16T23:27:11.341722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-16T23:27:11.432934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-16T23:27:55.798013+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=thenewslab.herokuapp.com request_id=3428bce1-739d-47ed-9205-9859475e0e22 fwd="46.69.82.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-16T23:33:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user joshuamacleod@live.com
2021-05-16T23:36:06.038437+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user joshuamacleod@live.com
2021-05-16T23:36:06.038437+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 31855de1 by user joshuamacleod@live.com
2021-05-16T23:36:06.264449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-16T23:36:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-16T23:36:19.886178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/server.js`
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175404+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175424+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175425+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175425+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175426+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/build/server.js'
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175426+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175427+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175427+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175428+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175428+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175429+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: []
2021-05-16T23:36:22.175429+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-16T23:36:22.240102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-16T23:36:22.322859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-16T23:36:50.313742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=thenewslab.herokuapp.com request_id=0e8e0047-c98d-4126-9008-c50c7d927320 fwd="46.69.82.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-16T23:43:04.802415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-16T23:43:19.981689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/server.js`
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004092+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004127+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004127+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004128+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004128+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/build/server.js'
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004130+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004130+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004130+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004131+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: []
2021-05-16T23:43:22.004131+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-16T23:43:22.064674+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-16T23:43:22.121461+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-16T23:56:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user joshuamacleod@live.com
2021-05-16T23:58:17.578622+00:00 app[api]: Release v18 created by user joshuamacleod@live.com
2021-05-16T23:58:17.578622+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 09023d82 by user joshuamacleod@live.com
2021-05-16T23:58:17.959761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-16T23:58:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-16T23:58:35.537730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809616+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809639+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809640+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809640+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809640+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/joshua/makers/thenewslab/news-server/db'
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809641+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809641+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/api/users.js
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809641+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809642+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809643+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809643+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809643+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809644+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/api/users.js:5:12)
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809644+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809644+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809645+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809645+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809645+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19) {
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809646+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809646+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/routes/api/users.js', '/app/server.js' ]
2021-05-16T23:58:38.809648+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-16T23:58:38.902832+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-16T23:58:38.974809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-16T23:58:38.986788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-16T23:58:50.650040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992272+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992286+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992286+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992286+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992287+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/joshua/makers/thenewslab/news-server/db'
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992287+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992287+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/api/users.js
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992288+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992288+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992288+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992289+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992289+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992289+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/api/users.js:5:12)
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992290+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992290+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992290+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992290+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992290+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19) {
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992294+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992294+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/routes/api/users.js', '/app/server.js' ]
2021-05-16T23:58:52.992294+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-16T23:58:53.061937+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-16T23:58:53.120732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-16T23:59:37.345240+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=thenewslab.herokuapp.com request_id=76cb051f-7ecc-451e-93cc-50f56beac59a fwd="46.69.82.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My server:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const passport = require("passport");
const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const path = require("path");

const db = require('./db')
const articleRouter = require('./routes/article-router')
const app = express()
const server = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))


require("./config/passport")(passport);

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.use('/api', articleRouter)
app.use("/api/users", users);

app.listen(server, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${server}`))
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "news-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 14.15.5",
    "npm": "6.14.11"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd news-front && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
  }
```

My Procfile:

```
web: node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

A Procfile is not always necessary to deploy Node.js apps to Heroku, however, your package.json is very very important. The package.json file should include the modules to be installed. Which is missing.

The logs clearly say code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', which means node_modules/ are missing.
You might have node_modules/ in your local system, but Heroku ignores it. It takes package.json and freshly starts to download it.

Heroku runs something like this. It Deletes node_modules/ then runs "npm install" then "node server.js"

For you, I would advice to always save your node_modules/ to package.json. This can be done while installing modules easily by adding --save

To debug this, do

"npm install --save express cors passport"

You can do this or do

"npm i --save express"

"npm i --save cors"

"npm i --save passport"

It is then showing me ./routes/api/users - I hope you have it.